# My DUPLO railroad engine stops after 20cm

Tags: trains, duplo, repair, electronics

My DUPLO railroad engine stops after 20cm moving.
I suppose the sensor in the front axle is damaged.

So is it possible to repair it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have red floor or carpet, that could be recognized as the [Stop Rail Accessory](https://brickset.com/parts/6225519/rail-accessory-no-4) by the engine. Otherwise I would contact Lego customer support.